# How do I reposition Conky?

Tags: 12.04, customization, conky

I successfully installed the **"Gotham" Conky** on my 12.04 desktop using [**these instructions**](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/09/install-gotham-conky-in-ubuntulinux.html)

It works perfectly, positioned in the top-right side of my desktop,  and I am happy every day of the week except "Wednesday".  Because of the length of the word "Wednesday", unfortunately the "y" trunctates off the screen (to the right).

I would like to reposition the conky, (preferablably keep it Top-Right) but nudge it to the left so the "y" is visible on the screen.

Any **"how to"** instructions will be gratefully received.

Comment: Open the conkyrc file, go to the bottom look for gap_y change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `.conkyrc` the alignment on the screen is is set to top_left:

```
alignment top_left
gap_x 60
gap_y 300
```

Simply change the alignment to top_right instead of increasing the gap_y variable:

```
alignment top_right
gap_x 60
gap_y 60
```

> [config file settings](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html)
>
> **alignment** Aligned position on screen, may be top_left, top_right, top_middle, bottom_left, bottom_right, bottom_middle, middle_left,
>   middle_middle, middle_right, or none (also can be abreviated as tl,
>   tr, tm, bl, br, bm, ml, mm, mr). See also gap_x and gap_y.